# Remove timestamp if data entry removed

Tags: excel, vba

I found this code online.

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A1:A1000")) Is Nothing Then
        With Target(1, 2)
        .Value = Date
        .EntireColumn.AutoFit
        End With
    End If
End Sub
```

If a value is placed into column A then today's date is put into column B.
If I remove the value from column A the date stays in column B.

Is it possible to remove the date in column B if column A is cleared of any values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below sub-

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A1:A1000")) Is Nothing Then
    '        With Target(1, 2)
    '        .Value = Date
    '        .EntireColumn.AutoFit
    '        End With
    
        If Target = "" Then
            Target.Offset(, 1) = ""
        Else
            Target.Offset(, 1) = Date
            Target.EntireColumn.AutoFit
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```